# Reading data that being printed in the terminal (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, ngrok

I am trying to write "bat" file for automatically start a couple of servers on win11 system and I am pretty new to PowerShell Script. The problem for me right now is - I want to create a job that starts in a separate terminal -> job should consist of 3 tasks:

1. run ngrok (yes I am a cheapskate) with ngrok http 2001
2. await 3 seconds for the server to start
3. get the data which was printed by ngrok (there are multiple lines)

The main problem is how can I read printfs(?) from the terminal?
p.s. I checked twice and didnt find any information regarding output of ngrok directly from execution, so readind terminal it is.

```
$command = 'ngrok http 2001'

Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList " -Command \`$command" -Wait -PassThru | ForEach-Object {
$_.WaitForExit()
$output = $_.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host $output
}
```

Really no clue what I am doing there

Comment: `Start-Process` is rarely used. Normally you should use commands directly, e. g. `ngrok http 2001`, which runs the command synchronously and shows its output in the PowerShell console. If you want to capture its output in a variable for further processing: `$output = ngrok http 2001`.

Comment: If you run `Start-Transcript -Path 'c:\path\to\file.log';` before the command you want to capture its output, it will write all output to the filename specified (and you can use Stop-Transcript to stop logging to the file). I would then just remove everything after `-Wait` in your start-process line. You can then use `Get-Content -Path 'c:\path\to\file.log'` to load the file contents and process it as required.

Comment: @MisterSmith Thanks for pointing out to me this function Start-Transcript!! Solved for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution for my specific problem with ngrok is:

Ngrok recently introduced `--log` flag, so the code basically is this -
`Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList @( '-NoProfile', '-Command "& {ngrok http --log=C:\path\to\file\output.log 2001}"' )` 
[More about --log](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/reference/ngrok/#flags-1)

### General solution to the problem of "How to read outputs from the terminal?" is:

`Start-Transcript -Path 'c:\path\to\file.log'` 
`Stop-Transcript`
[More about start transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3)
Credits to @MisterSmith!

Comment: PM from ngrok here. The ngrok agent also has an api available usually running at `http://localhost:4040/api` which can be used to fetch information about the currently running tunnel sessions. More info can be found in the [ngrok Agent API docs](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/reference/api/) but the endpoint you want is `GET http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels`.